# Function Calling and Redirecting through anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. I have four anchor tag in my page and there is a function called gen_all_es(). I want to call the function on every anchor tag click. Those anchor tag also contain href to another page. I want function call will be done first then redirect to another page. My anchor tag code is as follows. please check and let me know why function is not calling properly.

ASPX Code:

```
<a href="test.aspx?paramControl=imagePhoto" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" onclick="gen_all_es();">Add / Modify Photo</a>
```

JQuery Code:

```
function gen_all_es() {
        var divID, labelID, imageID, hiddenControlID, controlID, zoomLevel;

        $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="hf_es_text"]').each(function () {
            controlID = $(this).attr("id");
            divID = "lbl" + controlID.slice(11, controlID.length);
            labelID = "lbltext" + controlID.slice(11, controlID.length);
            zoomLevel = $("#ddlZoom").val();
            $(this).val(gen_es_text(divID, labelID, zoomLevel));
        });

        $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="hf_es_img"]').each(function () {
            controlID = $(this).attr("id");
            divID = "img" + controlID.slice(10, controlID.length);
            imageID = "image" + controlID.slice(10, controlID.length);
            zoomLevel = $("#ddlZoom").val();
            $(this).val(gen_es_image(divID, imageID, zoomLevel));
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide Javascript alongwith HTML

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha I didn't get what you are trying to say. please explain

Comment: Include your javascript code too in the question. Without that code, it's difficult to find the problem

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha I have updated my question with Jquery Function. Please check and reply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is working and function call is done first then redirection but you are not able to see the function call. I would suggest to add a delay in your function:

```
 setTimeout(function () {               
        }, 100); //in milliseconds
```

After this delay you will be able to see the result of function before redirection.

Comment: I have updated my question with JQuery Code, please check and let me know where I have to add your code.

Comment: You can use it before closing bracket "}" of function.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit. It might not be the best code but it might help you. 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/62/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('started');
    var divID, labelID, imageID, hiddenControlID, controlID, zoomLevel;
    $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="hf_es_text"]').each(function () {
        controlID = $(this).attr("id");
        divID = "lbl" + controlID.slice(11, controlID.length);
        labelID = "lbltext" + controlID.slice(11, controlID.length);
        zoomLevel = $("#ddlZoom").val();
        $(this).val(gen_es_text(divID, labelID, zoomLevel));
    });

    $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="hf_es_img"]').each(function () {
        controlID = $(this).attr("id");
        divID = "img" + controlID.slice(10, controlID.length);
        imageID = "image" + controlID.slice(10, controlID.length);
        zoomLevel = $("#ddlZoom").val();
        $(this).val(gen_es_image(divID, imageID, zoomLevel));
    });
    alert('done');
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  });
});
```

So instead of default browser redirect, I am using javascript to redirect the browser once the code is executed. Try if this helps you.

HTML: Remove inline javascript.

Comment: Your code is not working properly to solve my problem.